# meaning of the phrase "sitting on a tin-tack"

Tags: meaning

I am having problem with understanding the phrase  in this sentence. 
Orwell: If you have to define humor in a single phrase, you might define it as dignity sitting on a tin-tack.

What does it mean? 
I am not native English speaker. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, there is:

> [The English Dialect Dictionary](https://books.google.ca/books?id=c2kTAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&dq=%22tin-tack%E2%80%9D%20idiom&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5ic4Vca9AcykyASi04DoCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22tin-tack%E2%80%9D%20idiom&f=false) - Page 4 Joseph Wright
>
> **Tacket:** A small, broad-headed nail, esp. used for boots and shoes; **a
>   tin-tack**.

One must have humor to keep one's dignity when sitting on a nail (a quite uncomfortable, if not dangerous for one's bottoms, situation:-))